# How to sort find query by date?

Tags: nedb

I am inserting data using this query:

```
database.insert({ postedAt: new Date() }, (error: any, doc: any) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log ('Error inserting record in the database: ', error);
      } else {
        console.log('Document: ', doc);
      }
    });
```

This is stored in the database:

```
{"postedAt":{"$$date":1557753437242},"_id":"PJL2N6hfkvKnTTRK"}
```

Then I want to find data sorted by latest input to show up first:

```
    this.database.find({}).exec(function(err: any, docs: any) {  
      docs.forEach(function(d: any) {
          console.log('Found user:', d);
      });
    });
```

Question 1: But how can I ensure I get only the latest record? 
Question 2: How can I get all records within 24 hours?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/blob/master/README.md#sorting-and-paginating

Comment: That solves the first question @JuliaShestakova Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nedb supports sort by date out of the box, just sort it and limit 1

```
db.find({}).sort({postedAt: -1}).limit(1).exec((err, docs)=>{
    console.log(docs[0]);
})
```